# android.permission.read_phone_state not working

Tags: android, android-permissions, user-permissions

**I have added the permission for accessing phone_state but im still getting this exception " Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires READ_PHONE_STATE: Neither user 10052 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE."**

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
           <manifestxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.goh2.pronoornotepad" >
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_phone_state" />
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/pronoorpng"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".MainScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen" >
    </activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare the permission this way:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

instead of that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_phone_state" />
```